# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable in function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run the following code which counts the keywords in the specific value of the dictionary but it always shows me `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`as marked the error in the code as well. can someone please check and help me to solve this issue. Thanks

```
from collections import Counter
import json  # Only for pretty printing `data` dictionary.


def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: list[str]) -> dict[str, int]:
    return {
        word: count for word, count in Counter(text.split()).items()
        if word in set(keywords)
    }
// TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

def main() -> None:
    data = {
        "policy": {
            "1": {
                "ID": "ML_0",
                "URL": "www.a.com",
                "Text": "my name is Martin and here is my code"
            },
            "2": {
                "ID": "ML_1",
                "URL": "www.b.com",
                "Text": "my name is Mikal and here is my code"
            }
        }
    }
    keywords = ['is', 'my']
    for policy in data['policy'].values():
        policy |= get_keyword_counts(policy['Text'], keywords)
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code as-is works for me (or at least doesn't give a `TypeError`), on Python 3.9.

Comment: Using built-in types in hints like `list[str]` only became supported in Python 3.9.  I'm guessing you are on an older version of Python.  You can use `typing.List`/`typing.Dict`/etc. instead.

Comment: @0x5453 Exactly. Or just drop the type specifications if it is okay.

Comment: I'm running it on google colab and it gives me the above type error in this line `def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: list[str]) -> dict[str, int]:`

Comment: Please post the entire traceback message. It lets us know where the problem is.

Comment: I'm using python 3.9. Here is the entire traceback message.

`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-8ddaa2837c5a> in <module>()
----> 1 def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: list[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
      2     return {
      3         word: count for word, count in Counter(text.split()).items()
      4         if word in set(keywords)
      5     }

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I tried your code on python 3.9 and showed no error. Can you try `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` in your google colab and share your result? In default google colab setting it says 3.7.13

Comment: This is the result `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: `!python --version` shows me 3.9 while `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` shows me `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=13, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining type of your parameters then don't directly use `list` or `dict`, instead use `List` or `Dict` from `typing` module.

```py
from typing import List, Dict

def get_keyword_counts(text: str, keywords: List[str]) -> Dict[str, int]:
    ...
```

Comment: I'm doing the same.

`from typing import List, Dict` but it still shows the same error. I'm using python 3.9